# Birt and Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, birt

I'm trying to import the google analytics data to birt, I downloaded an open source plugin named [Google Analytics ODA Plugin](http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/devshare/designing-birt-reports/1489-google-analytics-oda-plugin/). when i form the next query it doesnt work.

query:

```
<query>
<dimension>ga:browser</dimension>
<metric>ga:visits</metric>
<startdate>2012-10-01</startdate>
<enddate>2012-10-31</enddate>
</query>
```

It doesn't give me any error - when the "OK" button was pressed, it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin tries to access a URL that returns a 404 Not Found error, and it doesn't show you that error (instead doing nothing). Google seems to have changed API and the plugin isn't updated for that yet AFAICS.